# Arithmetic Division in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

```
module averager(
    clk,
    rst,
    n,
    sum,
    cnt,
    out,
    avg
 );

input  [9:0] n;
input clk;
input rst;
output reg [19:0] out;
output reg [9:0] cnt;
output reg [19:0] sum;
output reg [9:0] avg;

integer i = 0;

always @(posedge clk ) 
    if (rst == 1) begin 
        sum = 20'b0;
        cnt = 10'b0;
        out = 20'b0; 
        avg = 10'b0;
    end else if (rst == 0) begin
        sum = sum + n;
        out = sum;
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        avg = 0;

        for (i=0; i<641; i=i+1) begin
            if(out >= cnt) begin
                out = out - cnt;
                avg = avg + 1;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

The above is the code to implement a cumulative moving average filter. The for loop is used for division to find the average and involves repeated subtraction. However I am getting the following warning and error:

**WARNING:Xst:2254 - Area constraint could not be met for block , final ratio is 509.
WARNING:Xst:1336 -  (*) More than 100% of Device resources are used
ERROR:Pack:18 - The design is too large for the given device and package.**

This must be because I am using large values in the for loop and thus am getting a large circuit that can't be implemented. I am looking for an alternative of the for loop, which could find the average for me. I just need the quotient value.

Design Properties: Family: Spartan3E Device: XC3S500E

Comment: This is the exact same question as: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163565/arithmetic-division-in-verilog

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29150941/1383356

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full [details answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/163646/17779) is with the [original posted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/163565/17779) on EE stack-exchange. This is the primary requierment for the solution:

> The for-loop logic is huge when it after it static unrolls. With your
>   current code, you cannot handle the worst case scenario where n=1023.
>   To cover this with your current code you'd need a for loop with 1024
>   iterations.
>
> Instead of a up counter, you can use a down counter and only examine a
>   slice of the array, where the index represents lsb of the array slice.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> for (i=10; i>=0; i=i-1) begin // lsb index of the slice
>   if (out[i+:10] >= cnt) begin // 10-bit slice compare
>     out[i+:10] = out[i+:10] - cnt; // 10-bit slice subtraction
>     avg[i] = 1'b1; // 1-bit assign
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> This for loop unravels to 11 iterations (10 to 0), each iteration only
>   looks at a 10 bit slice of `out` and only one bit of `avg`. You might
>   not be familiar with the `+:` operator. It is a bit-slice operator
>   introduced in IEEE Std 1364-2001. Left side if the start index
>   (dynamic is allowed) and the right side is the bit with offset (must
>   be a static constant). You can read more about it
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068296/1959732).
>
> Since it is a count down, we can can safely assume (proven
>   mathematically) the upper bits of the slice are zeros and we will
>   never have underflow with the guarding if condition. So we now have 11
>   10-bit subtracters each with 1-bit assigners which is much smaller
>   logic then the original 642 (should be 1024) 20-bit subtracters each
>   with 10-bit adder.